# Error installing libimobile device

Tags: compiling, make

So I want to install idevicerestore in my computer (Ubuntu 16.04LTS) but I have to install libimobiledevice first. When I type "brew install libimobiledevice", it fails when trying to install systemd. This is the output:

```
Installing dependencies for libimobiledevice: systemd, libusb, usbmuxd
==> Installing libimobiledevice dependency: systemd
==> Downloading http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/systemd-221.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /home/javi/.cache/Homebrew/systemd-221.tar.xz
==> ./configure --disable-silent-rules --prefix=/home/javi/.linuxbrew/Cellar/sys
==> make install
Last 15 lines from /home/javi/.cache/Homebrew/Logs/systemd/02.make:
Makefile:14182: recipe for target 'src/basic/libbasic_la-af-list.lo' failed

make[2]: *** [src/basic/libbasic_la-af-list.lo] Error 1

In file included from src/basic/arphrd-list.c:31:0:

src/basic/arphrd-from-name.h:125:1: error: conflicting types for 'lookup_arphrd'
 lookup_arphrd (register const char *str, register size_t len)
 ^
src/basic/arphrd-list.c:28:34: note: previous declaration of 'lookup_arphrd' was here
 static const struct arphrd_name* lookup_arphrd(register const char *str, register unsigned int len);
                                  ^
Makefile:14189: recipe for target 'src/basic/libbasic_la-arphrd-list.lo' failed

make[2]: *** [src/basic/libbasic_la-arphrd-list.lo] Error 1

Makefile:18384: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed

make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Makefile:19618: recipe for target 'install' failed

make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I'm a little bit noob, so any help is appreciated!